# J2ME calendar add date problem

Tags: java-me, calendar

I'm using eclipse pulsar under java vm 1.6 . the problem is `java.util Calendar` class add method raises an error **"The method add(int, int) is undefined for the type Calendar"** but its fine as per the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29).

```
package caltest;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletStateChangeException;

public class caltest extends MIDlet {

    public caltest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
// Subtract 5 days from the time in the calendar object
cal.setTime(new Date(cal.getTime().getTime() - 5 * 86400000));
```

or

```
// Subtract 5 days from "now" and set it in the calendar object
cal.setTime(new Date((new Date()).getTime() - 5 * 86400000));
```

?

Answer (score 3):

You say that you're using Java 1.6, but is that for your project or merely for running Eclipse?

If the project you're working on is running with the J2ME runtime, you should be looking at the documentation here:

- http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118

Specifically the [`Calendar` class](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Calendar.html)

An implementation of an "add date" method is described here:

- http://tcstechies.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/date-add-in-midp-j2me-calendar/

Comment: It may not be a good idea to reorder the libraries in CLASSPATH to make your code work with the Calendar class of Java SE API. The reason is that it might make your code work in the mobile emulator on your computer but when you move your midlet jar to an actual mobile phone, it may not work because most likely the mobile phone would have only the Java ME API and not the Java SE API.

Comment: @Paniyar, have a look [here](http://tcstechies.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/date-add-in-midp-j2me-calendar/)

Comment: @aioobe i tried that but it gave me wrong result for negative(-28) that is 28 days before current date as 1-6-2011